# OpenCV allocation causes segfault in std::thread::join

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11

The code below throws a segmentation fault inside the .join() of the std::thread class. However, that is happen only I use cv::fastMalloc to allocate a data array. If I use the 'new' keyword or the std::malloc function no error happens.

I need understand why this error happens because in fact I need a cv::Mat that uses this function.

```
int main() {
    uchar* data = (uchar*) cv::fastMalloc(640);

    std::atomic<bool> running(true);
    std::thread thread([&] () {
        while(running) {
            // I'll perform some process with data here
            // for now, just to illustrate, I put thread to sleep
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    running = false;
    // segfault is thrown here
    thread.join();

    cv::fastFree(data);
    return 0;
}
```

The GDB callstack follows below

```
#0 00429B26 _pthread_cleanup_dest () (??:??)
#1 003E32A0 ?? () (??:??)
```

Does anyone know what might be happening? I really think it is too crazy :S.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using? How are you compiling/linking? If that's all fine, looks like a clear cut bug.

Comment: `mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -lm main.cpp -o main.o`

`mingw32-g++.exe  -o main.o  -lopencv_core2410.dll.a`

MinGW 4.8.1 and OpenCV 2.4.10

Comment: No idea about mingw, but normally when you're using std::thread you'd need to link `-lpthread` as well.

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried it and had no effect. I also tried to set `-pthread`compiler flag and it not worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue reinstalling the opencv. Apparently the problem was the different versions of compilers that I had compiled the opencv and I'm using in this example.

For the record, I had compiled the opencv some time ago with a MinGW version that not support std::thread (I think 4.7.x).